# Sending an email behind the scenes in android

Tags: java, android, email

looking to have my app send an email to the users inputted email address. I have set up an email address through yahoo for my app, and was wonder what the best solution would be to send a file with the user only typing in their email address.

I already set up the code to create the file just looking for a way to send the email. Every search I've done requires the Intent and using the createChooser method which I want to avoid altogether since it wont send from my email to their email.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you like yourself, you will use a library like [JavaMail](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home)

You can find a stackoverflow post about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a), it contains useful examples

Comment: Thanks for such a fast response! I'll take a look into this :)